# NVIDIA Geforce Go 7300 automatically removed from blacklist when problems are solved?

Tags: unity, nvidia

Just a short question: Will we get an in formation when the issue with NVIDIA Geforce Go 7300 is fixed, resp. will the card removed automatically from the blacklist during the bugfix-update?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We won't update the blacklist in a stable release for UI consistency (I don't think that our user base would be pleased if we you update and you are transitionned into another UI at next reboot).

However, we will update that for the next ubuntu release of course (and hopefully, people will use that to create a PPA for natty users).

Comment: Thanx for clearing up. This make sense.